# Delete certificate from user local store using script

Tags: certificate, windows, certificate-authority

I manage to delete a certificate using a script with command :

**certutil -delstore -v -enterprise CA "Certificate CN"**

But unfortunately, it only works if this certificate was first added using the command :

**certutil -addstore -f -enterprise .....**

If I add a certificate manually, I can't manage to delete it with the script.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

**Try PowerShell**
PowerShell has a "Cert:" drive that you can navigate using the regular `cd` and `dir` commands.

There's a nice "Hey Scripting Guy!" blog post that talks about this:

- Microsoft TechNet Blogs, 2013-12-04, [Getting Started with PowerShell: The Certificate Provider](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/04/getting-started-with-powershell-the-certificate-provider.aspx) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/Gdet8).)

This command from the blog post looks like something you might want:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.IAMMRED> dir Cert:\CurrentUser -Recurse | ? subject -match 'test' | Remove-Item -WhatIf

What if: Performing operation "Remove certificate" on Target "Item: CurrentUser\Root\8A334AA8052DD244A647306A76B8178FA215F344 ".

What if: Performing operation "Remove certificate" on Target "Item: CurrentUser\Root\2BD63D28D7BCD0E251195AEB519243C13142EBC3 ".
```

Leave out the `-WhatIf` to actually delete certs.